# Route to a POST method with model and id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to pass in two Ids to my method. The method is called DeleteAttendee and is on my SessionController in the Training area.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteAttendee(int sessId, int attId)
```

I have created a link to get there that takes you to `https://localhost:<port>/Training/Session/DeleteAttendee?sessId=1&attId=3`.

```
<a asp-action="DeleteAttendee" asp-route-attId="@item.Attendee.Id" asp-route-sessId="@Model.Id">Delete</a>
```

Using the default routing, this page can't be found. What do I need to change or set up to route to this method?

Edit: Apparently the problem is that the link is performing a GET, but I need it to POST. How do I change it?

I think you can accomplish what I want to do with a `button` control. It will actually work better for me now if I can pass in the model and a specific id. I tried the button below. It looks correct in the markup, but the id keeps getting replaced with the sessionId when the button is clicked.

```
<button formaction="/Training/Session/DeleteAttendee/@item.Id" formmethod="post">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make HttpPost request to an action method in an ASP.NET MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450526/make-httppost-request-to-an-action-method-in-an-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a submit button that calls javascript and added the value to the viewmodel to get this done.

On the page:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectedAttendeeId" />
<input type="button" onclick="DeleteAttendee(@item.Id)" value="E" />
```

In javascript:

```
function DeleteAttendee(attendeeId) {
  var selectedAtt = $('#SelectedAttendeeId');
  selectedAtt.val(attendeeId);
  var model = $('#frmSession').serialize();
  $.post('/Training/Session/DeleteAttendee', model, function (data) {
    // success logic here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a `ActionLink` instead?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAttendee", "Session", new { sessId = Model.Id, attId = item.Attendee.Id })
```

Comment: That creates the same url with the same result.

Comment: Yes I can see that now, it doesn't take the subfolder in. Maybe this related post could be of help, especially the link to the video about areas: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992295/10161909)